# Setting up Eclipse and Maven to build a simple Jersey Webapp

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I had this working previously but had to reinstall everything because my hard drive died. I'm trying to build a simple jersey application via the archetype jersey-quickstart-webapp. The code is unchanged from the archetype so it's unlikely an issue with that as I had it working before the PC issue.

I'm fairly certain it's an install issue with Eclipse or Java or something else. My timeline of events goes as follows. I created the archetype project and got this error:

```
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:jar:2.2: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:pom:2.2 from/to central   (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out -> [Help 1]
```

From this I searched for solutions which included deleting the repository folder and everything in .m2, forcing the project to update dependencies etc.

While doing this I noted that the option to Run As-> Run On Server was not available as an option.

I went to manually add Project Facets > Dynamic Web Module, it said this requires Java 1.6 or newer. So I tried to lower the version all the way down to 2.2 which needs Java 1.3, none allowed me to check the box. I have Java 1.7 JDK installed.

This is where I stand. Can anyone please help!!?

Plugins installed into eclipse are: M2E, Collabnet Merge Client, Eclipse WTP

Comment: The problem is here: `central   (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out`. Fix you network issues (firewall/proxy?) Best to check a Maven build is from command line...

Comment: I don't think I've had any proxy settings set up previously...

Comment: Indeed it was the proxy settings. Thank you.